# Modern OpenGL for 2d graphics

Tags: opengl, 2d

I wanted to use Opengl for 2d graphics because of its hardware acceleration. Would you rather recommend me to use modern Opengl or to use the fixed pipeline for this? This whole shader
writing seems like too much overhead to me. I just want to draw some 2d primitives.

Comment: You better use some library like SDL. There are lot of them which use opengl behind the scenes and therefore have hardware accelerated drawing

Comment: thats exactly what I didn't want to do. I'd like to stay independent from such libraries

Answer (score 3):

Even for trivial 2d graphics using the *programmable pipeline* as opposed to the fixed function pipeline is what you want. In the end, the *programmable pipeline* gives you more freedom in expressing your graphics. How you decide to *program* the *pipeline* is up to you and is driven by your graphical needs. It could be, that you only need a single shader. There is no written rule that you need to have hundreds of shaders for it to be 'modern opengl'.

In that aspect it's debatable if modern opengl really is that much effort at all. It's a shader, a vertex/index buffers and a few textures. In comparison to fixed function pipeline, has it really changed that much that you even have to consider sticking to the fixed function pipeline?

A more compelling reason why you should prefer the programmable pipeline is that the fixed function pipeline is deprecated. In other words, pending removal. In concept a IHV could decide to drop support for it at any moment.

Comment: Lawrence, what if the 2d graphics are just images, i.e. you are looking for the equivalent of a bitblt? I have done some comparisons and could never get anywhere near the speed of DirectX. I am still having doubts if I did something wrong (like use "old" OpenGL) or that DirectX (Direct2D really) is just faster.

Comment: Performance is difficult subject, especially in hardware accelerated worlds where for the majority you simply don’t know what the hardware or rather said the driver is doing. There are quite many paths that easily deteriorate performance. The best you can do about that is to read about the recommendations given by industry professionals in presentations/talks etc – for example ‘Approaching Zero Driver Overhead in OpenGL’ gdc 2014. In keeping in mind that DirectX has a history of widespread usage of performance critical applications (i.e. games) it could very well be that it is actually faster.

Answer (score 0):

Modern OpenGL is better. Don't be afraid of shaders. Without them, you can't do anything besides draw the image using some blending... You can't go too far...
With shaders, you can do pretty much everything (effects like Photoshop, for example).